# Using io.popen effectively, or alternative solutions to it

Tags: winapi, lua

I'm not sure if there's a more efficient way to do this, though one person once stated they use Win32 API as opposed to io.popen. The problem is, I seem to lack skill to incorporate WinAPI into anything, though I'd love to use that if I could find a detailed, step-by-step instruction on makefile (or whatever I need to do) and making it work. But until then, this is the task at hand.

I'm currently using io.popen to return a ping result within a program that I use The problem is, it pops up the cmd box, and while it does so just briefly, it's annoying. This is what my code is:

```
pinghandle = io.popen("ping "..zs.params(2))
pingresult = pinghandle:read("*a")
pingmin = string.match(pingresult,"Minimum = (%d+ms)")
pingmax = string.match(pingresult, "Maximum = (%d+ms)")
pingavg = string.match(pingresult, "Average = (%d+ms)")
pinghandle:close()
if pingmin and pingmax and pingavg then
  send(zs.param(1),"@r{@x111Ping to @w"..zs.params(2).." @x111Min: @w"..pingmin.." @x111Avg: @w"..pingavg.." @x111Max: @w"..pingmax.."@r}@w")
else
  send(zs.param(1),"@x111Unsuccessful ping to@w",zs.params(2))
end
```

Pay no attention to the `zs.param(#)`. That's client specific and has no bearing on the code. My question is... is there an "invisible" way to achieve the same result? Barring that, is this as effective as I can make the code?

Comment: Is [LuaJIT](http://luajit.org/) an option for you? If so, the FFI can be quite handy for these sort of things.

Comment: It may, but my problem tends to be that I don't know how to compile source files. I've tried, in the past, to use makefiles, but I guess I'm just lacking something, and I get frustrated because I never can seem to get it to work. ** Edit: I think I've figured it out, will update once I know for sure.

Comment: This seems to be something I can work with. Thanks! I'll look more into it and see if I need help in the future!

Comment: what about `os.execute`?

Comment: @Josh: Makefiles are for when you need to compile lots of things that depend on each other, and you want to avoid recompiling everything if one of the files gets updated. Anyway, compiling things is not that hard and even if you get into a snag there is alsways stackoverflow for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various external libraries to let you do this for you.

Check out [winapi](http://stevedonovan.github.com/winapi/topics/readme.md.html), [apr](http://peterodding.com/code/lua/apr/docs/#process_handling) or [ex](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ExtensionProposal)

Comment: The problem is, I cannot seem to figure out how to install winapi. I don't have the luam command, which seems to be necessary for some reason, and there do not seem to be any installation guides for it whatsoever. I'll have to check out the other two though, see what I can learn from it.

Comment: huh? what is this luam thing? Download winapi @ https://github.com/stevedonovan/winapi or binaries at https://github.com/stevedonovan/stevedonovan.github.com/tree/master/files (theres different binaries depending on your lua runtime)

Comment: Right, when I makefile with your second link, it tries to execute a luam command. Looking at the first link, it appears that's where it's coming from. Going to try it now, then. Thanks!